# MSMQ Message Viewer?

Tags: msmq

I have messages in a MSMQ queue and I would like to view the full message.

I know I can write code to peek the queue, but was wondering if there is a viewer that already exists that will let me read the entire message?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are a few options - all I found are commercial (not terribly expensive, but not free, either):

- [Mqueue Viewer](http://www.mqueue.net/) (free)

[image]

- [Mulholland Q Set](http://www.mulhollandsoftware.com/QSet/QSet.aspx)

[image]

- [QueueExplorer](http://www.cogin.com/mq/index.php)

[image]

Comment: Thanks marc_s! We went with Queue Explorer.

Comment: Queue Explorer +1, love this tool.

Comment: MSMQ Inspector has a free standard version - http://viridissoftware.com.au/Products/MSMQInspector#editions

Comment: Seems the MSMQ Studio project has ended according to the homepage.

Comment: MQueue viewer didn't show any queues under private queues. Queue Explorer lists them without a problem.

Comment: Mqueue offers the ability to view the Extension data, which is critical for us.  Many of the other viewers I've tried do not.

Comment: The amount you pay for the OS, MS should at least add some basic management features like remove a single message!

Answer (score 44):

If you are using Visual Studio - Open Server Explorer under Servers/[Server Name] there is Message Queues folder that gives you view as well.

Comment: Huh. I never thought to look here. However, maybe I'm missing something... I can see the queues, but I can't browse them or view messages. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also, I just got an error in VS2012 using this method that has locked me up real good...

Comment: @DaveZiegler - You can Right click "Refresh", expand, then for a particular message you can view it's properties.  Then when you view the properties You can see the "Body Stream" property is probably a `System.Io.MemoryStream`, and click the ellipsis to the right of that (after clicking it).  It's round about but this worked for me.

Comment: The interface isn't ideal, but it's great to quickly view messages.  I had no idea this existed.  +1

Answer (score 40):

MSMQ QXplorer

Free. Open source.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/msmqqxplorer/

Comment: See Daniel Halan's solution - much better.

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to run in Windows 2012 R2.

Answer (score 19):

You can get to a snap-in here:
Computer Management > Services and Applications > Message Queuing

According to:
http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/how-can-i-view-msmq-messages-and-queues/

Answer (score 12):

Service Bus MQ Manager is a free open-source tool I wrote to monitor the MSMQ in real-time for any incoming messages, it supports coloring and formatting of XML and JSON messages.

http://blog.halan.se/page/Service-Bus-MQ-Manager.aspx

Comment: Disclaimer: Service Bus MQ Manager is under RPL 1.5 license which makes all "Derivative works" also open source if you want to use it freely - http://opensource.org/licenses/rpl1.5.txt .

Comment: Blog site seems down, code is here: https://github.com/danielHalan/ServiceBusMQManager/issues

Binary still available through web archive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200430113948/http://blog.halan.se:80/page/Service-Bus-MQ-Manager.aspx

Answer (score 1):

MSMQ Studio is an MSMQ management tool that allows you to view and send messages and manage your local and remote queues.

*** NOT AVAILABLE ANY MORE ***

[image: MSMQ Studio]

Comment: Seems gone, or is it available somewhere else?

Comment: I removed it as I didn't want to support it anymore since MSMQ support has been removed from never versions of .Net.