# MSMQ. Displaying message body

Tags: c#, .net, queue, message-queue, msmq

I faced the problem of display message body. I send test message (using XmlFormatter) to queue using C# (I have Windows 7).

How can I remove hex from message body preview?

[image]

I found interesting moment: if body less 612 bytes - xml display is ok, but if body more 612 bytes - appears hex.

[image]

I can't use BinaryFormatter, because I need show in the message property (body) clear xml. (If use BinaryFormatter, hex displayed too).
I tried create custom (TxtFormatter) formatter - hex displayed too.

Comment: Can't you just do a messagequeue.peek?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491801/msmq-message-viewer

Comment: I can. But I need read message using this window (message - property - body). And I can not use any other programs to view the queue. Only standard tool.

Comment: Then you can't change this behvior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Just need use [ActiveXMessageFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.activexmessageformatter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Good you found a solution. Please mark this as your answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`XmlMessageFormatter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.xmlmessageformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) while passing a non-XML string, you should ensure the following:

1. If message is an object, ensure that it has the attribute `[Serializable]`. Otherwise, the message body will be hexadecimal format.
2. Ensure the resulting serialized object attributes map correctly and have valid values, if defined in an XSD (XML Schema Definition) file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use MSMQ Studio to view MSMQ messages. https://msmq-studio.com